# How to have a unique record created for each year, but then distinct records created for each value (NOT A DUPLICATE)

Tags: oracle, plsql

So currently I am trying to insert aggregated (summed) data into a table called **Value**. I am trying to create a record in the **Calculation** table for each unique year that I am able to derive from my cursor. Then I am trying to insert these relationships into the **Value_Calculation_Rel** Table. If the group_level is '6' I will be inserting 'YEAR_PEAK_COLOR' into the **calculation_name** column.  If the value for group_level is '4', I will be inserting 'YEAR_PEAK_SHAPE' into the **calculation_name** column.
So essentially I want a single record in the **Calculation** table for each year. Then in the **VALUE** table I want a distinct record for each value that I calculate (whether it be a sum for a color, shape or a max for a color, shape grouped by **YEAR**). I then want records in the **Value_Calculation_Rel** table showing the relationship between the records in **Calculation** and **Value** (by Year).

The end result that I want looks like this:

**CALCULATION TABLE**

```
 CALCULATION_ID    CALCULATION_DATE     CALCULATION_NAME    REPORT_PERIOD
      1               sysdate          'YEAR PEAK COLOR'         1-1-2017
      2               sysdate          'YEAR PEAK SHAPE'         1-1-2017
      3               sysdate          'YEAR PEAK COLOR'         1-1-2018
      4               sysdate          'YEAR PEAK COLOR'         1-1-2019
      5               sysdate          'YEAR PEAK SHAPE'         1-1-2019
```

**VALUE TABLE**

```
  VALUE_ID         VALUE             YR
     1              55               1-1-2017
     2              10               1-1-2017
     3              18               1-1-2018
     4              22               1-1-2019
     5              77               1-1-2018
     6              101              1-1-2019
     7              33               1-1-2019
```

**CALCULATON_VALUE REL TABLE**

```
 CALCULATION_VALUE_ID    CALCULATION_ID   VALUE_ID    SHAPE      COLOR
      1                      1              1          null       RED
      2                      2              2         CIRCLE      null
      3                      3              3          null       BLUE 
      4                      4              4          null       BLUE
      5                      3              5         SQUARE      null
      6                      4              6          null       RED
      7                      5              7         SQUARE      null
```

Below is my code (that is currently creating a new Calculation record for each Value, which is incorrect):

```
create or replace procedure STORED_PROC
IS
CURSOR c1 is
select
  trunc(hr, 'yyyy') yr,
  shape,
  sum(value) total,
  max(value) maxval,
  color,
  grouping_id(trunc(hr, 'yyyy'), shape, color) AS group_level_nb
from value v
join calculation_value cv on v.value_id = cv.value_id
group by cube (trunc(hr, 'yyyy'), shape, color);
  l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
  v_value_id value.value_id%type;
  v_calculation_id calculation.calculation_id%type;     
--
BEGIN                                          
IF l_var.group_level_nb = '6'
THEN
    INSERT INTO CALCULATION(calculation_id, calculation_date, calculation_name, report_period_dt)
                        VALUES (null, sysdate, 'YEAR_PEAK_COLOR' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss'), l_var.yr)
 returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
    INSERT INTO value(value_id, value, yr)
               VALUES (null, l_var.total, l_var.yr)
               returning value_id into v_value_id;
    INSERT INTO calculation_value (calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, color)
                             VALUES (null, v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.color);
commit;
--
ELSIF l_var.group_level_nb = '4'
THEN
    INSERT INTO CALCULATION(calculation_id, calculation_date, calculation_name, report_period_dt)
                        VALUES (null, sysdate, 'YEAR_PEAK_SHAPE '  || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss'), l_var.yr )
                        returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
--
     INSERT INTO value (value_id, value, yr)
                    VALUES (null, l_var.maxval, l_var.yr)                        returning value_id into v_value_id;
    INSERT INTO calculation_value (calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, shape) 
VALUES (null, v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.shape);        
END IF;
--
commit;
--
END STORED_PROC;
```

Please let me know if there is any further information that I may have left out that I need to further add. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `value` table you describe does not have a `hr`, `shape`, `value_nb` or `color` column but you are referencing them in your stored procedure's cursor. Please include a [MCVE] where your description matches your code - preferably including DDL/DML statements for your tables and sample data.

Comment: hey @MT0, 'yr' is derived from using the trunc(hr, 'yyyy') function, value_nb = value ( that was a typo, sorry) and the shape and color columns are from the calculation_value REL table (as shown in the code). All I really need to know is how to create a new record in calculation for each distinct cube, but also tie each unique value in the REL table to the calculation_id based off the (cubic) groupings. (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that first checks whether the record is already present in CALCULATION TABLE and only adds a line if it is not. In both scenarios, you then have v_calculation_id available for your next steps. I didn't write it out with your cursor and everything, but it should be easy for you to replace your `INSERT INTO CALCULATION` with my `select CALCULATION_ID [...] returning t.CALCULATION_ID into v_calculation_id`. HTH

```
create sequence seq;
create table tab (
    CALCULATION_ID number default on null seq.nextval not null enable,
    CALCULATION_DATE date,
    CALCULATION_NAME varchar2(100),
    REPORT_PERIOD varchar2(100));

declare
    v_calculation_id   number;
    v_CALCULATION_NAME varchar2(100) := 'name';
    v_REPORT_PERIOD    varchar2(100) := 'period';
begin
    begin
        select CALCULATION_ID into v_calculation_id 
        from tab where CALCULATION_NAME = v_CALCULATION_NAME and REPORT_PERIOD = v_REPORT_PERIOD;
        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            insert into tab t
            (CALCULATION_ID, CALCULATION_DATE, CALCULATION_NAME , REPORT_PERIOD)
            values (null, sysdate, v_CALCULATION_NAME , v_REPORT_PERIOD)
            returning t.CALCULATION_ID into v_calculation_id;
    end;
dbms_output.put_line(v_calculation_id);
end;
/

select * from tab;
```

**Edit due to comment:**

you did not provide the full procedure and some things are not adding up - e.g. one time a column in table `CALCULATION` is called `REPORT_PERIOD` and another
time it is `called report_period_dt`. another example: in the sample data, the value of `CALCULATION_NAME` is e.g. `'YEAR PEAK COLOR'`, but in the procedure you fill it like so: `'YEAR_PEAK_COLOR' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss')` - so above, I decided to give you a technical example instead of altering your procedure. but given the uncertainties mentioned above i meant you replace like so (and likewise for `l_var.group_level_nb = '4'`):

```
[...]
IF l_var.group_level_nb = '6'
THEN
    INSERT INTO CALCULATION(calculation_id, calculation_date, calculation_name, report_period_dt)
                        VALUES (null, sysdate, 'YEAR_PEAK_COLOR' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss'), l_var.yr)
 returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
    INSERT INTO value(value_id, value, yr)
[...]
```

becomes

```
[...]
IF l_var.group_level_nb = '6'
THEN
     begin
        select CALCULATION_ID into v_calculation_id 
        from CALCULATION where CALCULATION_NAME = 'YEAR_PEAK_COLOR' and REPORT_PERIOD = l_var.yr;
        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            insert into CALCULATION t
            (CALCULATION_ID, CALCULATION_DATE, CALCULATION_NAME , report_period_dt)
            values (null, sysdate, 'YEAR_PEAK_COLOR' , l_var.yr)
            returning t.CALCULATION_ID into v_calculation_id;
    end;
    INSERT INTO value(value_id, value, yr)
[...]
```

Comment: are we setting the value for v_calculation_name to 'name' in the WHERE clause? That may not work right?

Comment: @JohnWick I updated my answer for you to make it clearer. hth